# jQuery 3.3.1 no actualiza el atributo 'value' cuando cambio el valor de un input

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando el atributo 'value' para comprobar el valor de un input, cuando cambio el texto en el input, la funcion de jQuery .val() reconoce el nuevo valor pero el atributo 'value' sigue manteniendo el valor anterior. No entiendo  este comportamiento, en versiones antiguas de Jquery sí funciona OK. Podéis comprobar lo que digo en el ejemplo que dejo a continuación.

http://jsfiddle.net/XWNmd/574/

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

No lo tienes que insertar como `attr` sino como `val`

```js
$('#link').val('value');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' value='http://www.link.com' id='link' />

<input type="button" value="prueba" onclick="alert($('#link').val())"/>
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, el valor se lo cambias a mano en el input pero no lo reconoce.

Comment: te he añadido fiddle porque si que funciona

Answer (score 0):

Se debe a que en un caso traes un `atributo`, que toma el valor que tiene al inicio, es decir, al crear el html, mientras que en el caso de usar `val()` estás trayendo la `propiedad` valor, la cual si cambia al modificar el valor del input. Se implementa desde jQuery 1.6.

Tanto atributos como propiedades pueden ser modificados por jQuery.

Puedes ver más [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8312820/5675636).

Answer (score 0):

La solución a tu problema es muy sencilla, lo unico que tienes que hacer es detectar cuando cambia el valor del dicho input utilizando eventos y luego ese valor asignarlo al elemento que quieres modificar. Ejemplo:

```js
//Detectamos cuando hay cambios.
$('#link').on('change', function(e){
    //Y a la vez en el callback obtemos el valor introducido por el usuario
    //y simplemente al atributo del elemento le asignamos el valor introducido
    $("#link").attr('value', e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' value='http://www.link.com' id='link' />

<input type="button" value="prueba" onclick="alert($('#link').attr('value'))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

En un comienzo, el atributo `value` del input es igual a su valor, por lo tanto

```
console.log(jQuery('#link').attr('value'));
```

Es consistente con el valor inicial. Después de cambiarlo, este comando sigue informando el valor inicial.

Si tu haces en cambio:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('link').value);
```

Obtienes el nuevo valor del input.

**¿Por qué pasa esto?**

Esto pasa porque jQuery hace un **poblamiento inicial** de los **atributos** del elemento html basado en todas sus **propiedades** y **atributos** indistintamente.

Después de cambiar el valor, la **propiedad** value del elemento ha cambiado, pero los datos que jQuery usó para poblar `attr` no cambian para ciertas **propiedades**, como el `value` de un input de tipo text, o el estado `checked` de un checkbox porque, repito, son **propiedades** y no **atributos**.

Ocurre que en las últimas versiones de jQuery (desde la 1.6 en adelante, en realidad), hay una diferenciación entre las propiedades y los atributos:

```
console.log(jQuery('#link').attr('value')); // no habrá cambiado
console.log(jQuery('#link').prop('value')); // sí habrá cambiado
```

Haz la prueba cambiando el valor del input en el siguiente snippet y usando los botones que mandan a la consola el **atributo** value y la **propiedad** value.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#link').on('keypress change', function() {
    jQuery('#prueba_attr').removeAttr('disabled');
    jQuery('#prueba_prop').removeAttr('disabled');
  });

  jQuery('#prueba_attr').on('click', function() {
    console.log("attr('value') sigue siendo ", '"' + $('#link').attr('value') + '"');
    console.log("input value ahora es ", '"' + document.getElementById('link').value + '"');
  });

  jQuery('#prueba_prop').on('click', function() {
    console.log("prop('value') ahora es ", '"' + $('#link').prop('value') + '"');
    console.log("input value ahora es ", '"' + document.getElementById('link').value + '"');
  });
});
```

```css
#link {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type='text' value='cambia mi valor para habilitar los botones' id='link' />

<input type="button" id="prueba_attr" value="prueba attr" disabled/>
<input type="button" id="prueba_prop" value="prueba prop" disabled/>
```

**Nota al margen**: `jQuery('#link').val()` delega a la propiedad value de un input, no al atributo value. Por eso sí te funciona.

**Nota al margen 2**: el uso de `jQuery('#link').attr(x)` cambió en jQuery 1.6, pero en la 1.6.1 [intentaron revertirlo a como era antes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/). Esto ha ido evolucionando en versiones posteriores, **pero si bien funciona en algunos casos**, lo recomendado sigue siendo usar `jQuery('#link').prop(x)` cuando se trata de un input.